# Kubernetes - free claimed resources of a Pod in a failed state

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I have got the following template for a job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "gpujob"
spec:
  completions: 1
  backoffLimit: 0
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 600000
  template:
    metadata:
      name: batch
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: "test"
      containers:
        - name: myhub
          image: smat-jupyterlab
          env:
            - name: JUPYTERHUB_COOKIE_SECRET
              value: "sdadasdasda"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 500Gi
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: 1
          command: ["/bin/bash", "/usr/local/bin/jobscript.sh", smat-job]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
      restartPolicy: Never
      nodeSelector:
        dso-node-role: "inference"
```

As you can see, I claim a lot of memory for the job. My Question is: Does the failed pod free the claimed resources, as soon as it is on a failed state? Due to regulations, I have to keep pods for one week in the cluster, otherwise I would just set a very low `ttlSecondsAfterFinished`. I read a lot of contradicting stuff in articles, but found nothing in the official docs.

[image]

**TDLR: Does a failed Pod free claimed resources of a cluster? If no, what is a good way to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a failed or completed job will produce a container in [Terminated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-state-terminated) state, and therefore the resources allocated to it are freed.

You can easily confirm this by using the command:

```
kubectl top pod
```

You should not see any pod associated with the failed job consuming resources.